# Jersey and JSONConfiguration serialization an emplty list and single element list

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I'm struggling with serialization an emplty list and single element list in Jersey for days now. I searched a lot I couldnt find a solution for my problem. I tried to fix it by adding JAXBContextResolver class. The goal is to return JSON object that contains JSON array to my Android application in all cases (if it returns 0 element or 1 element or more than 1).  I tried JSONConfiguration by using `MAPPED` and `NATURAL` JSON notations. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

I used `NATURAL JSONConfiguration` as presented in this question :

[Jersey serialize empty list and single element list as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674207/jersey-serialize-empty-list-and-single-element-list-as-an-array)

But I think the better way is to use `MAPPED JSONConfiguration` but the problem with this configuration that it working only for one Class and It is not resolving the issue with the empty list. Please I really need your help

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver < JAXBContext > {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class[] types = {Workitem.class, Project.class, User.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("workitem").build(),
                types);

    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class objectType) {
        for (Class type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried this solution 
[How can I customize serialization of a list of JAXB objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json/3143214#3143214)

But I really need JSON Data to look like this :

```
{
    "project": [
        {
            "assignedTo": "assignee1",
            "businessKey": "Key1",
            "createdBy": "createdBy1",
            "description": "description1"
        }
    ]
}
```

And for the empty list to look like this :

```
   {
        "project": []
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried jersey-json ?

Comment: Actually that is what I'm using I Added jersey-json to my maven dependencies then I used JAXBContextResolver, Is that what you mean or I misunderstand ?